# Multiple onblur elements gives error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am try to call a function onblur of my three elements in my table

but i am getting this error in my console

"**((m.event.special[e.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || e.handler).apply is not a function**".

So onblur these elements i want to call my function.Please do have a look at my code once.

Apologies for my bad handwriting here .I am new to javascript

```
jq.ajax({
        url: '/soap/ajax/36.0/connection.js',
        dataType: 'script',
        success: function() {
            jq(document).ready(function() {
                // call tookit dependent logic here
                jq('#gbMainTable').on('blur', 'tr.dr td[name="v4"] select','tr.dr td[name="v6"] select','tr.dr td[name="v7"] input', function() 
                { 
                    var thisInput = this;
                    console.log('thisInput.value',thisInput.value);
                    var thisInput1 = jq(this);

                    var thisRow = thisInput1.parents('tr.dr:first');
                    console.log('thisRow',thisRow);

                    var agentInput1 = thisRow.find('td:eq(7)');
                    console.log('agentInput1',agentInput1);
                    var finds1 = agentInput1.find('select');
                    console.log('finds1',finds1);
                    var agentInput2 = thisRow.find('td:eq(8)');
                    console.log('agentInput2',agentInput2);
                    var finds2= agentInput2.find('input');

                    if(agentInput1.text()!=='' & thisInput.value=='Programmable Cntrls/Welders/AC Drives/Soft Starts'){
                        exampleFunction('Programmable',agentInput1.text(),agentInput2.text());
                        console.log('YES');
                    }
                    else if(agentInput1.text()!=='' & thisInput.value=='Electro Mechanical'){
                        exampleFunction('Electro-Mechanical',agentInput1.text(),agentInput2.text());
                    }
                });

            });
        },
        async: false
    });

    function exampleFunction(Warranty,Years,charge) {
        var state = { // state that you need when the callback is called
              output : null,
              startTime : new Date().getTime()};

          var callback = {
              //call layoutResult if the request is successful
              onSuccess: doThis,

              //call queryFailed if the api request fails
              onFailure: queryFailed,
              source: state};

         sforce.connection.query(
             "SELECT InOut__c,PlantPct__c,T37Pct__c,TotalPct__c,Type__c,Warranty_Code__c,Years__c FROM WarrantySpecialLine__c where InOut__c = '" +charge+"' and Years__c = '"+Years+"' and Type__c = '" +Warranty +"'",
              callback);
    }

    function queryFailed(error, source) {
        console.log('error: '+error);
    }

    /**
      * This method will be called when the toolkit receives a successful
      * response from the server.
      * @queryResult - result that server returned
      * @source - state passed into the query method call.
      */
    function doThis(queryResult, source) {
        if (queryResult.size > 0) {
            var output = "";

            // get the records array
            var records = queryResult.getArray('records');

            // loop through the records
            for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                var warrantySpecial = records[i];

                console.log(warrantySpecial.PlantPct__c + " " + warrantySpecial.TotalPct__c + " " +warrantySpecial.T37Pct__c );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you setting up a `document.ready()` callback in the success callback of your AJAX call?

Comment: When you see that error in your console, what file does it say the error is occurring in?

Comment: gb-edit.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: ((m.event.special[e.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || e.handler).apply is not a function
    at HTMLTableElement.dispatch (gb-edit.js:3)
    at HTMLTableElement.r.handle (gb-edit.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (gb-edit.js:3)
    at Object.simulate (gb-edit.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.c (gb-edit.js:3)

Comment: gd-edit.js is the file ?

Comment: Yes, it appears so. This means that the issue is occurring within that file and is most likely because you are not passing or calling that library on the proper element in your code. You should step through your code to see which exact line of your code is the culprit.